# Error Call to a member function get ProductName () Error in configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, fatal-error

I have a little big problem. After the migration of the catalog for a new store in a "clean" installation of Magento I started to have problems with configurable products. When you select an option and click buy, instead of adding the product to cart, returns the error message:

> *Fatal error: Call to a member function setProductName () on a non-object in
>   /home/alter648/public_html/compras/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 387*

Searching on the internet I found something similar in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414137/cannot-add-to-cart-configurable-product-after-migration-magento but that did not solve.

Already checked the records of the configurable product and simple products, and found no difference in relation to the registration in the previous store. I checked and saved and changed nothing.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you migrated the catalog.
The error appears if there is not stock record for the product you are trying to add to cart.
You can try a reindex, but I doubt that will solve it.
But I bet the problem will be solved if you edit the product in the backend and save it.
Of course, this is not a solution if you have a lot of products in your store, but it's at least a starting point.

Comment: Tks Maius. But in this case the stock isn't managed.

Comment: It does not matter. Even if the stock is not managed, a record for the stock should be present in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record as solved:
I solved the problem by simply opening the simple and saving products.
I think that's what was presented as a solution on the link below, but I understood it was to access the configurable product, and not simply as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You imported programmatically your products, but did you initialize stock ?

**Even if stock are not managed in Magento, each products must have an entry in stock model 'cataloginventory/stock_item'.**

To create stock model assigned to product, you can use something like :

```
if (!$stockItemId) {
    Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
        ->assignProduct($product)
        ->setData('stock_id', 1)
        ->setData('store_id', 0) // You can use Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() if needed
        ->setData('manage_stock', 0) // Magento wont manage stock
        ->setData('qty', 1) // But Qty is 1
        ->setIsInStock(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::STOCK_IN_STOCK) // And product is in stock
        ->setProcessIndexEvents(false) // Speed up you update script (usefull for synch scripts)
        ->save();
        $resultmaj .= 'stock initialisé, ';
}
```

Finally, reindex everuthing just in case :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can cause because of following reason
->All the attributes that you had in previous store has not been added in attribute sets. Re-indexing might solve the problem afterwards.
Solution: 
Create all attributes that were present in previous store and update it via magmi for configurable product if there are any. And Another solution is as @marius  suggested edit and save manually. Shortcut would be selecting all product and add `"<NULL>"` in description with editing attributes.